# Can we attach topics to temporary queues in solace

Tags: solace

I have a use case where I publish to a topic and listen via Queues in solace. Due to the increased number of Queues , we have decided to create temporary queues. When I tried with a temp Queue, I was able to publish and subscribe directly. But I'm unable to attach a topic endpoint to the queue. Is it possible t attach a topic endpoint to a temp Queue in Solace, if so how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Which API are you using? Assuming it is the Solace Java API, then to add a topic subscription to a queue you can use the `JCSMPSession.addSubscription(...)` method. For other Solace APIs see the documentation here: https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/API-Developer-Guide/Adding-Topic-Subscriptio.htm

The process is same whether the queue is temporary or durable.

```
Queue queue = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createQueue("Q/tutorial/topicToQueueMapping");
Topic tutorialTopic = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createTopic("T/mapped/topic/sample");
session.addSubscription(queue, tutorialTopic, JCSMPSession.WAIT_FOR_CONFIRM);
```

In the add subscription method above pass in your temporary queue object reference.